# message of my notification not display in notification bar ,only title?

Tags: android

I try to display database content (just two word ) in message of notification but only the title appear  why?.
second problem : i used AlarmManager to trigger an intentservice class (class that content this code) every 1 min but if data ==null it's notify me while in my condition that have to not to be happened

```
 ShowTimeDB RetrieverDB =new ShowTimeDB(this);
    RetrieverDB.open();
    String data = RetrieverDB.getShowNotify();
    RetrieverDB.close();

    if (data!=null){

        nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);




        Intent intent=new Intent(this,TodayShow.class);
        PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        CharSequence x=(CharSequence) data;
        Notification n=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"YOU HAVE SHOw" ,System.currentTimeMillis());
        n.setLatestEventInfo(this, "ShowTime", x, pi);
        n.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

        nm.notify(uniqueID,n);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Notification.Builder instead of Notification. Building Notification objects using new Notification() has been deprecated in favor of using Notification.Builder class. THere is also a NotificationCompat.Builder for compatibility with versions back to 1.6.

I'm not sure what you mean by your second question.

Comment: thanks, about second problem this code above when (if (data!=null)) when data content  equal to null the code inside if block should not work , but in my case the code work in spite of data equal null !